# How can I echo sweet alert message to the user when login

Tags: php, html, echo, display, sweetalert

I am making login page with database validation and I want to display sweet alert message when ever there is an error or when when the user successfully provide the details how I I so that?

Comment: People expect to see what you tried (your code), in a well formatted question. Help them help you. Please take the [**stack overflow tour**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know more about this site, and read about **[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with jquery and ajax.
Your javascript:

```
$('#login_signin_submit').click(function(e) {
        $('#YourFormID').ajaxSubmit({
                    url: 'login-proccessing.php',
                    success: function(response, status, xhr, $form) {
                        if (response) {
                           //Success message
                        } else {
                           //Fail message
                        }
                        
                    }
                });
    });
```

Comment: There are many conditions and I want to display all types of conditions in alert.If there is any way that I can use php condition in javascript, that would be appreciated

Comment: Michael you have to provide more information or at least some code to fully understand what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks Edvinas I found a way to do that